# How to use moment in nestjs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, momentjs, nestjs

I want to use momentjs in a nestjs app, and also be able to test my services. 
So I provided momentjs as below in my module

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: 'MomentWrapper',
      useFactory: async () => moment(),
      scope: Scope.REQUEST,
    },
  ],
```

and in my service

```
    constructor(
        @Inject('MomentWrapper') private momentWrapper: moment.Moment
    )
```

Then I have a method like this

```
    private calculateNextRun(every: number, period: SchedulePeriod): string {
        const currentDate = this.momentWrapper.tz('America/Toronto');
        let nextDate = null;

        nextDate = currentDate.add(every, period);
        console.log(currentDate.format(), nextDate.format(), every, period, );

        return nextDate.toISOString();
    }
```

This method will be called in a loop, and supposed to get the current date and add some days/weeks/.. to it and return it.

The issue is it keeps the old value so each time it goes into the method is not starting from current date

console output

```
2020-01-25T16:39:19-05:00 2020-01-25T16:39:19-05:00 6 d
2020-02-15T16:39:19-05:00 2020-02-15T16:39:19-05:00 3 w
2020-02-16T16:39:19-05:00 2020-02-16T16:39:19-05:00 1 d
```

If you see first date, which is `currentDate` keep changing

Is there any way to overcome this issue, **without** creating a new service like this

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
@Injectable()
export class MomentService {
    moment(): moment.Moment {
        return moment();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work when you define your provider as `useValue: moment` and then call `this.momentWrapper().tz(...`?

Comment: @KimKern I changed it to what you asked, anyway I get syntax error for `this.momentWrapper()` , BUT if I use my old syntax with your changes, seems it's working

Comment: @KimKern please post it as answer to accept

Comment: This is a typescript issue importing the package see the answer below 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71943285/8255981

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a new moment instance for each function call and not reuse the same instance of your provider singleton. So provide `moment` instead of `moment()`:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: 'MomentWrapper',
      useValue: moment
    },
  ],
```

Comment: could you please share the reference that how to inject the `moment` in `service.ts` file

Answer (score 7):

This works fine for me:

```
// in some *.service.ts
import * as moment from 'moment';


{ userIsRegistredOn: moment()}
```

Comment: could you please share the complete example of the code?
FYI: typo `import from`